# How to use logging, pytest fixture and capsys?

Tags: python, unit-testing, logging, pytest

I am trying to unit-test some algorithm that uses logging library.

I have a fixture that creates a logger.

In my **1st test case**, I do not use this fixture and uses a print to log to stdout. This test case **passes**.

In my **2nd test case**, I use this fixture, but not as documented in pytest doc. I just call the associated function in my test to get the logger. Then I use the logger to log to stdout. This test case **passes**.

In my **3rd test case**, I use this fixture as documented in pytest doc. The fixture is passed as an argument to the test function. Then I use the logger to log to stdout. This test case **fails**! It does not find anything in stdout. But in the error message, it says that my log is in the captured stdout call.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import pytest

import logging
import sys

@pytest.fixture()
def logger():

    logger = logging.getLogger('Some.Logger')
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    stdout = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    logger.addHandler(stdout)

    return logger

def test_print(capsys):

    print 'Bouyaka!'

    stdout, stderr = capsys.readouterr()
    assert 'Bouyaka!' in stdout

    # passes

def test_logger_without_fixture(capsys):

    logger().info('Bouyaka!')

    stdout, stderr = capsys.readouterr()
    assert 'Bouyaka!' in stdout

    # passes

def test_logger_with_fixture(logger, capsys):

    logger.info('Bouyaka!')

    stdout, stderr = capsys.readouterr()
    assert 'Bouyaka!' in stdout

    # fails with this error:
    # >       assert 'Bouyaka!' in stdout
    # E       assert 'Bouyaka!' in ''
    #
    # tests/test_logging.py:21: AssertionError
    # ---- Captured stdout call ----
    # Bouyaka!
```

There is no change if I reorder the test cases by the way.

Answer (score 14):

Thanks a lot for your ideas!

Reverse `logger, capsys`, make `logger` request the `capsys` fixture and use `capfd` do not change anything.

I tried [pytest-catchlog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-catchlog) plugin and it **works fine**!

```
import pytest

import logging

@pytest.fixture()
def logger():

    logger = logging.getLogger('Some.Logger')
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    return logger

def test_logger_with_fixture(logger, caplog):

    logger.info('Bouyaka!')

    assert 'Bouyaka!' in caplog.text

    # passes!
```

In my original tests, I logged to stdout and stderr and captured them.
This is an even better solution, as I do not need this tweak to check that my logs work fine.

Well, now I just need to rework all my tests to use caplog, but this is my own business ;)

The only thing left, now that I have a better solution, is to understand what is wrong in my original test case `def test_logger_with_fixture(logger, capsys)`.

Answer (score 7):

As of pytest 3.3, the functionality of capturing log message was added to pytest core. This is supported by the caplog fixture:

```
def test_baz(caplog):
    func_under_test()
    for record in caplog.records:
        assert record.levelname != 'CRITICAL'
    assert 'wally' not in caplog.text
```

More information can be found at the [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/logging.html)

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing the logger gets created (via the fixture) before the `capsys` fixture is set up.

Some ideas:

- Use the [pytest-catchlog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-catchlog) plugin
- Maybe reverse `logger, capsys`
- Make `logger` request the `capsys` fixture
- Use `capfd` which is more lowlevel capturing without altering `sys`